# org-mode, ox-html publishing: avoid superscript/subscript when using `^` or `_`

Tags: emacs, publish, org-mode

When publishing an org-file to html via `org-publish-*` the exporter translates `a_b` to `a<sub>b</sub>` and `a^b` to `a<sup>b</sup>`. Is there a way to avoid that? I don't use formatting in my todo org files at all, so disabling this reformatting alltogether would be totally fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Export options](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings) let you control if and how markup is interpreted.

In particular, the option `^:nil` will disable interpretation of superscripts and subscripts.

For example, adding

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
```

to the top of a file will do the job.

Comment: Great, exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you very much!